# How to remove this <hr> with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to use CSS to remove a horizontal line.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div id='page'>
<div id='header'>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
```

I tried using:

```
#page hr:first-child{display:none;}
```

But that doesn't work. I need to display other hr's so I can't just remove them all. I need to target just this one.

Comment: `hr:first-child` means “The `hr` which _is the first child_”, not “The first `hr`”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it without `:first-child` (the first child of `#page` is `#header`)

```css
#page > hr {display:none;}
```

```html
<div id='page'>
<div id='header'>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
```

Note: The `>` isn't really necessary - it's just a bit more precise

Note: If there is more than one `hr` inside the same parent, you can use `#page > hr:nth-of-type(x) {display:none;}` , with x being the count for the hr inside the parent

Comment: this will hide any hr that is a child of #page

Comment: In the example that's in the question there's only one hr in there.

Comment: The OP state: "I need to display other hr's so I can't just remove them all"

Comment: If there were more than one, maybe he'd like to hide the second one?

Comment: So, it's `#page > hr:nth-of-type(x) {display:none;}` , with x being the count for the hr inside the parent

Comment: yeah, that would be better

Answer (score 5):

try this one

```
#page hr:first-of-type{display:none;}
```

this will hide the first `hr` that is a child of `#page`